# Spring Boot testing with different service class

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, kotlin

I have a pretty basic question, apologies if it has been asked before. I fear I may not be using the right words, this is my first rodeo with Spring.

I have a `RestController` declared as such:

```
@RestController
class TelemetryController {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var service: TelemetryService
    //...
}
```

with a concrete implementation of `TelemetryService` as such in our `main` module:

```
@Service
class ConcreteTelemetryService : TelemetryService {
   // some production code
}
```

I then have a service I want to use in my controller during tests (inside our `test` module:

```
@Service
class TestingTelemetryService : TelemetryService {
   // some test code using local data
}
```

Critically, I have do NOT want to use Mockito for this, as the implementation of the tests require very specific setup that is not appropriate for Mockito.

My test is declared as such:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class HowDoInjectServiceExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc
}
```

How do I get my `TestingTelemetryService` inside my controller in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various way to achieve this but I would recommend to use Spring Profiles.

Use the default profile with the concrete implementation. This bean will be used if no profile is specified.

```
@Profile("default")
@Service
class ConcreteTelemetryService : TelemetryService {
   // some production code
}
```

Add the profile "test" to the test implementation.

```
@Profile("test)
@Service
class TestingTelemetryService : TelemetryService {
   // some test code using local data
}
```

Now you can start your test with

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

Read more about profiles here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: As an addendum, I added `spring.profiles.active=test` in my `application.properties` file in both the resource directory within the test module. Seems a bit better than using cmdline arguments and slots into IDEA well.

Answer (score 0):

If your `TestingTelemetryService` is in same package as `HowDoInjectServiceExampleTest` then you can simply autowire test bean like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class HowDoInjectServiceExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Autowired
    var service: TestingTelemetryService
}
```

if not then you should define some `TestConfiguration` and programatically define bean with service name and use it using @Qualifier in test to resolve which bean to use (in your case its test bean)

Comment: This did not work for me, though everything is in the same package.